# We couldn't merge these cases. when merging account

Tags: account, person-accounts, merge

I am actually having issues when merging two account or person accounts. Even if they do not have cases related to them, I am encounting the following error :

We couldn't merge these cases.An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 467951362-160534 (798706858)

Even as a system administrator I'm getting the error. Do someone know why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rollup summary field on the account object was causing the issue. The formula in the rollup was referencing an incorrect field. But what is strange is why it was throwing error only on merging and not when there were update on the record. Nevertheless I hope this can help other people in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Internal tools show the following error for error ID: 467951362-160534 (798706858)

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid Summary Filter Formula? Field
> 00N0Q000001QJCc is inaccessible. Please review all fields referenced
> by the formula. Context: common.config.field.FormulaFilterContext

As the error message indicates you must be using invalid summary filter formula for the picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions.

[Tips for Working with Picklist and Multi-Select Picklist Formula Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=tips_for_using_picklist_formula_fields.htm&type=5)

I have seen similar issues and below is an example where R&D has provided the following resolution. Posting it here for your reference

Resolution: R&D found that several roll-up summary/formula fields were actually pointing to a previous field product_family_old_c. In order to fix this issue, we need to have customers go to the "Where is it used?" button on the Product_Family_c field on the Order Product object. From there they need to navigate to all the custom field references and edit those fields, force recalculate any roll-up summary fields and then save. This ultimately resolved the issue.

If you are unable to identify the issue, I recommend raising a support case

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is the error field for account fields or case fields?

Comment: It is for Account fields

Comment: @vanessen - Let me know if the information I shared is helpful

Comment: Actually i have a case open for verification by Salesforce. I take into consideration your comments and investigated but couldn't find any fields on the accounts that may be the problem. I elt you know when SF answer. Thansk anyway.